# using Position:fixed into radwindow in IPad

Tags: css, telerik

```
  <div class = "divwhole">
       <div class="divfixed">

       </div>
       <div class="divscoll">

       </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```css
.divfixed{
position:fixed;
}
```

I try position: fixed using radwindow.It work in computer browser but no work in I Pad. How to solve it?

Comment: `position: fixed` is supported in iOS5 and above. Which version are you using?

Comment: IOS5, when I scroll it, the fixed div also move it.

Answer (score 0):

What does RadWindow have to do with this? I don't see it around. Check you code for typos or other issues (like another CSS rule with higher specificity being present).

If you want to have a RadWindow fixed on the screen - use its Pin behavior. its client-side API is useful - the isPinned() and togglePin() methods to be more precise.